# How many social security numbers are there that have increasing digits?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A social security number is a sequence of 9 digits. How many social security numbers are there 
$$n_1n_2n_3 ...n_9$$ 
such that $n_i \leq n_{i+1}$ for $i \in \{1,...,8\}$? For example, $024455888$ would count but $254180419$ would not.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Please edit your question text to show what you've tried so far and, in particular, had difficulty with.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on formatting math for this site.

Comment: Do you know about stars and bars ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm ??

Answer (score 1):

If there are no restrictions as in William Elliot's answer, then define $n_0=0$ and $n_{10}=9$.  Let $x_k=n_k-n_{k-1}$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,10$.  Then each SSN with increasing digits is in a $1$-to-$1$ correspondence with a sequence $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{10})$ of non-negative integers such that 
$$x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_{10}=9.$$
By the stars-and-bars method, the number of SSN with increasing digits is then
$$\binom{9+10-1}{10-1}=\binom{18}{9}=48620.$$

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult problem because not all 9 diget sequences are social security numbers.

The first three digits are the location code.
Not all 1000 possibilities are used.
237-246, 587-665, 667-679, 681-699, 750-772 Not Issued
734-749, 773-899 Unknown
000, 666, 900-999 Never valid numbers

700-728 issuance of these numbers to railroad employees was discontinued July 1, 1963.

Any number beginning with "000", "666", "900-999", has a middle "00", or ends in "0000" will never be a valid SSN.